# Can you do Natural left join in JPA SQL javaEE?

Tags: java, jpa

```
List<Users> temp2;
temp2 = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Users u "
        + "NATURAL LEFT JOIN CourseMembers b "
        + "WHERE b.courseMembersPK.userID IS NULL").getResultList();
```

Hi! I'm trying to get all the user objects if there is no records of them in another table (`CourseMembers`).

But I'm getting this error from my `EJB`:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT u FROM Users u NATURAL LEFT JOIN CourseMembers b WHERE b.courseMembersPK.userID IS NULL]. 
[21, 22] The FROM clause has 'Users u' and 'NATURAL LEFT JOIN CourseMembers b' that are not separated by a comma.
[30, 30] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.
```

I have tried with a comma, but it gives me another error. How can I solve this?

Comment: In this query language you have to work with the object structure.

Comment: So you're not allowed to use join's at all?

Comment: you can use joins. But not natural joins

Comment: Basic JPQL documentation would answer that http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/jpql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a scenario where you want to get all the users that are NOT members/subscribed to any courses.

At first you should create a `OneToMany` relation between the `User` and the `CourseMembers` entities:

In the `User` entity you should have something like:

```
...
private Set<CourseMembers> courseMembers;
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="user")
public Set<CourseMembers> getCourseMembers() {
    return this.courseMembers;
}
...
```

Then you need a `ManyToOne` relation between the `CourseMembers` and the `User`:

In the `CourseMembers` entity you should have something like:

```
...
private User user;
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", nullable=false)
public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}
...
```

And then, in your query you can use:

```
FROM User u WHERE u.courseMembers IS EMPTY
```

Hope this helps.